# Error While saving list workflow in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create custom workflow using SharePoint workflow 2013 at client side.While I am saving this, it thowas error-"Server side activities have been updated. You need to restart  sharepoint designer to use the updated version of activites"

I have installed 32-bit sharepoint designer 2013 in my system and I have no access to server.

I have also followed the solution and deleted the contents in the below location. But error remain like this. I have also re-installed the designer.

```
<user profile>\appdata\roaming\microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
<user profile>\appdata\local\microsoft\websitecache\<sitename>
```

Please help to solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am late to answer here, but I was facing same problem and i found exact solution, the actual culprit is Workflow client installed with Visual studio. Just uninstall it from Program and Features in control panel

Comment: I have the same setup (VS2015 updated, SPD2013 against SP Online) Microsoft has a support KB that is meant to fix the issue support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114337 Installing that KB did not fix the error for me. Uninstalling the Workflow Manager Client from programs and features (as mentioned) fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

When the site is accessed via SPD from any other box besides the WFE/Workflow manager host server, the error is not encountered and its possible to save/publish workflows.

- [Reference Link.](http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/Error_while_saving_a_workflow_via_sharepoint_designer:_Server-si/?TopicId=67706&Posts=1)